# Using Twitter API has started giving a Sorry Page does not exist error even though it worked earlier on

Tags: php, twitter

I am working on a php project where I am trying to post a message onto Twitter. I have the following code to authenticate twitter, when I was working on it about 30 minutes ago it was working fine and I could successfully authenticate, get my profile pic and username without any problems. Below is the code.

```
function authenticate($oauth_token)
        {
            require ("../../../libraries/twitterLib/secret.php");
            $twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
            $twitterObj->setToken($oauth_token);

            $token = $twitterObj->getAccessToken();
            $twitterObj->setToken($token->oauth_token, $token->oauth_token_secret);
            $_SESSION['ot'] = $token->oauth_token;
            $_SESSION['ots'] = $token->oauth_token_secret;
            $twitterInfo = $twitterObj->get_accountVerify_credentials();
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($twitterInfo->response);
            echo "</pre>";
            $username = $twitterInfo->screen_name;
            $profilePic = $twitterInfo->profile_image_url;

            echo $this->addToDatabase($username, $profilePic, $token, $_GET['oauth_verifier']);
        }
```

Once this was working I then tried to post a message but got a `Sorry, that page does not exist` error code 34. I thought I was only having a problem with posting, but then I tried to delete my oauth token and re-authenticate and now the above code that worked half an hour ago is no longer working and I am getting the below output

```
Array
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [message] => Sorry, that page does not exist
                    [code] => 34
                )

        )

)
```

I don't understand why I am getting this all of a sudden when it worked a moment ago and now doesn't, this part of code hasn't changed since it was working.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: See https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10803

Comment: "Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!"...

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58964014/1617737

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already fixed the problem by changing the API connection URLs on EpiTwitter.php:

```
class EpiTwitter extends EpiOAuth
{
  const EPITWITTER_SIGNATURE_METHOD = 'HMAC-SHA1';
  protected $requestTokenUrl= 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
  protected $accessTokenUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token';
  protected $authorizeUrl   = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize';
  protected $authenticateUrl= 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate';
  protected $apiUrl         = 'https://api.twitter.com';
  protected $searchUrl      = 'http://search.twitter.com';
```

Anyway, you better update files from https://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async/tree

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, they must have changed the URLs in between me writing the authentication code and posting to twitter.

Comment: search.twitter.com is deprecated, and API calls must include a version (https://api.twitter.com/1) @see Twitter API docs

Answer (score 2):

For [Twitter search](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets), I found that we could not send search requests through https://api.twitter.com/1/search.json anymore.

Need to use https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json instead.

Comment: Not true, you need to specify a version since now, i.e api.twitter.com/1 . Also search.twitter.com is deprecated. You should migrate to API 1.1 : api.twitter.com/1.1

Comment: Twitter's [API 1.0 docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) give `http://search.twitter.com/search.json` as the search url. Though deprecated, as of this comment, it's still working. Twitter has warned that they will be intermittently turning off API 1.0, and that at an unspecified date will turn it off completely.