# Twitter Login Stopped Working "sorry, that page doesn't exist"

Tags: ios, twitter, parse-platform, http-status-code-404, fabric.io

I'm logging users in with twitter using the PFTwitterUtils loginWithBlock: method. This has always worked fine and the name of my app appears above the username and p/w ready for user input.

However, recently (which may or may not correspond to installing Fabric.io) the modal display that appears, after entering the username and password and pressing authorise app, returns this image:

[image]

Has something changed with the sdk lately? Or have i made a silly error while changing something. In short, what is the cause of this error?

Comment: Did you install the Twitter login part of Fabric?

Comment: I think I did. Could that interfere?

Comment: I think that may be the problem.  Fabric's TwitterKit Sign In With Twitter does not use the same Consumer Secret and Consumer Key that you created for your app at apps.twitter.com.  If you want to use PFTwitterUtils, I think you'll have to remove the TwitterKit Sign In and then recreate your Consumer Secret and Consumer Key at http://apps.twitter.com

Comment: Brilliant, I'll get on that later this evening and tell you how it goes!

Comment: Hi, they both point to the same twitter sign in. I set one up with Fabric now and tried using the Fabric sign in and that doesn't work either. It just keeps giving me this message, regardless of which platform I use to sign in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that under settings>twitter log in, my application had been switched off in there and therefore it kept throwing up that message. It really should have the capacity to notify the user when such an instance occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem today. The [Twitter API Status page](https://api.twitterstat.us/) wasn't showing any problems, so I tried logging in with a different Twitter user account and it worked fine. So if you are having the same issue as the OP, it may be your user account that has the issue - possibly due to oauth/login overusage.